# Is this possible with cURL?

Tags: curl

In short: I want to login some users to other sites with my login details.

It would look like this for example with rapidshare:
I would put the rapidshare link in an iframe on my site.
Before the iframe loads, i would place the rs logged in cookies at the users browser, and do a POST data on the login action page with my login details, so the users are logged in automaticly.

I don't care that thay can change the password then etc., i just only need to know if this workaround is possible or not.

Comment: "i would place the rs logged in cookies at the users browser" - what?

Comment: our site will create the cookies that RS would create on successful login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly this isn't possible, and cURL in particular isn't going to help. cURL would need to run on the client to manipulate and transmit cookies its own set of cookies, and cURL wouldn't be able to touch the browser's cookies.  Sorry.